# Is cryptsetup benchmark for single or multiple queues

Tags: encryption

Let say that cryptsetup benchmarks gives 2 GiB/s performance. Is it per queue so on 4 core processor I could read from disk at 8 GiB/s (assuming I wasn't limited by SATA etc. and it would scale perfectly) or does it already take it into account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cryptsetup benchmark` only uses a single core. You can see this in `top` while it's running, it never goes beyond `100%` of one core only.

I'm not quite sure how `cryptsetup benchmark` performance relates to actual performance on physical storage media; a `tmpfs` based loop device gives `2GiB/s` according to `pv`, while the benchmark says `2666.5 MiB/s`.

So expect slightly lower speeds than the benchmark claims.

As for scaling to multiple cores, not sure if that's a thing nowadays. I guess no since if it was I'd expect the `cryptsetup benchmark` to scale accordingly, too. But that's just a guess. Used to be you had to use multiple LUKS containers (and multiple readers on those containers) to get multiple cores working on encryption.